# Retrieve Cell Value in Excel with largest date between duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following columns in an excel sheet in Excel 2010:

```
Batch Number        BatchID            END TIME
120319-0001     120319-0001_TEST1   3/20/12 13:44
120319-0001     120319-0001_TEST2   3/20/12 10:05
120319-0002     120319-0002_TEST1   3/20/12 14:40
120319-0002     120319-0002_TEST2   3/20/12 12:46
120319-0003     120319-0003_TEST1   3/20/12 14:01
120319-0003     120319-0003_TEST2   3/20/12 12:11
120319-0004     120319-0004_TEST1   3/20/12 15:37
120319-0004     120319-0004_TEST2   3/20/12 11:59
120319-0005     120319-0005_TEST1   3/20/12 19:06
120319-0005     120319-0005_TEST2   3/20/12 11:47
```

I need a formula I can fill down in the 4th column that will do the following:

- Select all duplicates in column "Batch Number"
- Find Max in column "END TIME" for duplicates
- Fill 4th column with the Cell Value in Column "BatchID" on Max in "END TIME" on all duplicates

Expected output of 4th column:

```
120319-0001_TEST1
120319-0001_TEST1
120319-0002_TEST1
120319-0002_TEST1
120319-0003_TEST1
120319-0003_TEST1
120319-0004_TEST1
120319-0004_TEST1
120319-0005_TEST1
120319-0005_TEST1
```

I've tried using a combination of `INDEX`, `MATCH`, and `IF` statements and haven't gotten it to work yet.

I would be willing to work with a VBA/macro solution too.

Comment: The output, i guess you took that from a larger dataset? If so could you remove the ones that are not in your example dataset? (might be wrong, after re-read)

Comment: @NickSlash Yes these are a pseudo modification from the original dataset which has > 50,000 rows and more columns

Comment: is it practical to do a sort first to assist with a 1 time fx?  Or does this need to be an ongoing live formula?

Comment: @Kevin I do a sort on BatchID to bring all duplicates in "Batch Number" together for my attempts but a sort can be done on any of the columns before a fill down of the column. It does not need to be a live formula

Comment: @jordanhill123 HEY PAL!!!!!!!!

Comment: try in `D2`: `=LOOKUP(2,1/FREQUENCY(-1E+99,-(A$2:A$11=A2)*C$2:C$11),B$2:B$11)` then fill down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick go trying to do it with Formulas, but I think you'd possibly need to use Array formulas and they make no sense to me!

The following macro should do it though. (could be an issue comparing the timestamps though)

```
Sub Main()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Data As Range

Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Data = Sheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Range("A" & Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row)

Dim BatchNumber As Variant
Dim EndTime As Variant
Dim Result As Variant

BatchNumber = Data.Value2
BatchID = Data.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value2
EndTime = Data.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
Result = Data.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value2

Dim Index As Integer
Dim Lookup As Integer
Dim Max As Integer

For Index = LBound(BatchNumber, 1) To UBound(BatchNumber, 1)
    Max = Index
    For Lookup = LBound(BatchNumber, 1) To UBound(BatchNumber, 1)
        If BatchNumber(Lookup, 1) = BatchNumber(Index, 1) Then
            If Not Lookup = Index Then
' NOTE: you might to do stuff to the date/time comparison below to get it to work correctly
                If EndTime(Lookup, 1) > EndTime(Index, 1) Then
                    Max = Lookup
                Else
                    Max = Index
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Lookup
    Result(Index, 1) = BatchID(Max, 1)
Next Index

Data.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value2 = Result

End Sub
```

**Update**

The following one should be a bit quicker as it only iterates over the dataset <strike>once</strike> twice. Instead of Rows*Rows iterations (i think) for the first.

```
Sub Main2()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Data As Range
Dim vData As Variant
Dim vResult As Variant
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Data = Sheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row)

vData = Data.Resize(ColumnSize:=3).Value2
vResult = Data.Value2
Dim List As Object

Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim Index As Integer
Dim Key As String

For Index = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
    Key = vData(Index, 1)
    If List.exists(Key) Then
        If vData(Index, 3) > vData(List(Key)(1), 3) Then
            List(Key)(1) = Index
        End If
    Else
        List.Add vData(Index, 1), Array(Index, Index)
    End If
Next Index

For Index = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
    Key = vData(Index, 1)
    vResult(Index, 1) = vData(List(Key)(1), 2)
Next Index

Data.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value2 = vResult

Set List = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You could speed up the subroutine by checking if there are more than one batch number in the collection (according to first step in the question). Possibly `Filter` function would useful.

Comment: The "select duplicates" is (i beleive) just to compare the `end time` values and select the largest for the result

Comment: I think some of the batch numbers could not be repeated on the list. Anyway, using `dictionary` is much better I think.

Comment: @NickSlash I'm only getting the first row to populate in the 4th column. Any ideas? Same result with both `Main` and `Main2` routines

Comment: Are the column references correct? if your data is not in columns `A:C` + `D` for the results they might not work as expected.

Comment: @NickSlash I ended up modifying the `Set Data` line as follows `Set Data = Sheet.Range("A2:D" & Range("A" & Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row)` and it works great! I only tried `Main1` as it takes about 20 minutes to run on my data set but the output is what I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @NickSlash I really could have done that like this though: `Set Data = Sheet.Range("A2:D" & Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)` couldn't have I?

Comment: @jordanhill123 indeed you could. You might want to give `Main2` a try as it should be much faster.

Comment: @NickSlash I also had to change `Index` from `Integer` to type `Long` for my larger dataset due to overflow.

Comment: @NickSlash `Main2` completes in  under 2 secs for about 52,000 rows compared to ~ 15 minutes for the first one in my attempts. Only change I had to make to `Main2` was setting `Index` to Type `Long`. Thanks for the assist!